# URLSession implementing URLSessionDelegate to bypass any certificate verification

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

I have an iOS framework that is a networking module. I need to bypass certificates, but every solution I find is always based on this one, which didn't work for my situation.

```
extension FCSession: URLSessionDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        
        switch challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod {
        case NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust:
            if let serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust {
                let credential = URLCredential(trust: serverTrust)
                
                completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
            }
        default:
            completionHandler(.rejectProtectionSpace, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

This is log of error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
    "<cert(0x10880ac00)
```

I've already tried passing the completionHandler directly with the serverTrust, and receives a same result error.

completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))

Comment: In the `default` case you should probably choose `performDefaultHandling`. Also, make sure _every_ code path eventually calls the completion handler with an appropriate disposition (which is not the case in your code!). I also want to make it abundantly clear, that when ignoring the server trust, you put yourself at high risk! Don't release this code! Except for testing or debugging, it makes no sense to do this usually, since there are better options.

Comment: Even for debugging or testing, it makes no sense to do this, because there are better options.  A cert from letsencrypt is free.  There is absolutely never any good reason whatsoever to do this.  But if you *insist* on doing this, at least do it right, accepting the cert only if the key matches the expected public key for your server (pinning) by calling `SecCertificateCopyKey` or `SecTrustCopyPublicKey` followed by `SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation`.